# Missing files for wordpress civicrm docker-compose setup

Tags: docker

I'm working on a wordpress docker-compose setup for civicrm.

https://gitlab.com/opencoders/fslubu/docker

The dockerfile copy the civicrm plugin folder from the host to the docker volume.
But I can't find the civicrm folder in wordpress plugins folder in the container.
RUN curl and unzip in dockerfile has the same issue too.

Thanks a lot
Christian

Comment: First thing that comes to mind, - did you check the permissions for other plugin folders, is it the same?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x    3 www-data www-data      4096 Jul  6 17:38 plugins (in mounted container volume)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/opencoders/fslubu/docker/-/blob/master/wordpress-civicrm/images/wordpress/Dockerfile
https://gitlab.com/opencoders/fslubu/docker/-/blob/master/wordpress-civicrm/docker-compose.yml

Comment: 404 Page Not Found for both. Private repository?

Comment: you must have a .env in root folder 
here a default config as example
https://gitlab.com/opencoders/fslubu/docker/-/blob/master/.env.default

Comment: sorry repo is public now

Comment: I ran docker build for the Dockerfile and then created the container. The folder is there.
`docker run --rm test ls /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins` prints
`civicrm`

Comment: yes, you are right. I can reproduce this. why can't see the civicrm folder in portainer console for this container?

Comment: I looked up what portainer is, installed it and inspected the same container's plugins folder and `civicrm` is still there. https://prnt.sc/193nrm7

Comment: Recreate the volume was the solution: 
```docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -v```
```docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q )```
```docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d``` 

I can see the civicrm folder with command:
```docker-compose run --rm wp ls /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins```

Comment: with ```docker-compose run --rm wp sh``` the civicrm folder is missing. why can I see the folder with ```docker-compose run --rm wp ls /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins```?

Comment: I removed the COPY in Dockerfile and replaced to 
```WORKDIR /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
RUN curl -L https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-${CIVICRM_VERSION}-wordpress.zip > civicrm-wordpress.zip
    && unzip civicrm-wordpress.zip
    && rm civicrm-wordpress.zip```